# get difference between two dates in years in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document

```json
   {
      name: "Pedro",
      birthdate: ISODate("1987-05-18T00:00:00Z"),
    }
```

I'm starting with mongo and I need to return the name, date of birth and age. how do I get the age in years? I've been trying this way

```js
db.Pessoa.aggregate( [ { $project: { name: 1, birthdate:1, dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$birthdate" ] } } } ] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a simple `$dateDiff` with `endDate: "$$NOW"`. Set `unit` to be `year` to get difference in years.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      birthdate: 1,
      dateDifference: {
        "$dateDiff": {
          "startDate": "$birthdate",
          "endDate": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "year"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oSZ2mWaT2qN) for your reference.